# How to open two files (first hidden) in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I want to open two files a row (first hidden) in vbscript. I have wrote script that opens only one hidden file, but I have no idea how to open second.

'HideBat.vbs
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "file.txt", 0, True,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would expect this to work by just duplicating the line of code you already have. The second parameter (`0`) would then hide the window.

However, when looking at [the documentation](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) for this parameters, it appears that *Not all programs make use of this.* Indeed, when I try this on my machine, which has Notepad++ as default editor for `.txt` files, the window is *not* hidden. Other options, such as 'Minimize' (`7`) will work, but only if the application is not yet opened.

Maybe you could update your question and tell is what it is you want to achieve. There may be other ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, you have the right. I have deleted ", 0" and now it works :) Thanks